# perl program to validate user input by comparing existing array

Tags: perl

Im trying to write a Perl script to validate user input.
If the user provide wrong value then it should show which is wrong value among the provided user input.

Example:

I have any array `@arr=qw/cat rat mat sat/;`

If user provide the input as `perl validate_user_input.pl cat sot bat` then, my script should show `sot bat` is wrong inputs to the script.

below is the script im trying .

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@not,@arr,$flag);
@arr=qw/cat rat mat sat/;
my $count=@arr;
foreach (@ARGV)
{
         my $i=1;
        foreach my $existing (@arr)
        {

                until ( "$existing" eq "$_" )
                {

                        $flag = 1;
                        $i++;
                        last;
                }

        }

        print "$i\n";
        if ( ($count==$i) && ($flag == 1))
        {
                push(@not,"$_");
        }
}
print "@not\n";
```

Logic i tried to implement:

Element in `@ARGV` will be checked against each element of `@arr`. If `$flag=1` and the iteration `$i` is equal to number of elements in `@arr` (i.e checked against all the elements in `@arr`) then input not found in `@arr`.

Can anyone tell me what need to be done for this script to work.

Comment: `until` => `if` for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a short search of this site would lead me to believe you are over-complicating things:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@not,@arr);
@arr=qw/cat rat mat sat/;

foreach (@ARGV)
{

        push(@not,"$_") unless ( "$_" ~~ @arr );
}
print "@not\n";
```

The smart match operator (~~) still comes back as 'experimental' on my 5.24 version of bash, but it would seem it has been around since at least 5.10.

You may also want to add some kind of test at the end to check if @not has anything in it as all words may have been found.  You could re-use your flag :)

Answer (score 1):

Too complicated. Turn your 'valid' args into a hash, then use `grep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @allowed = qw/cat rat mat sat/;
my %is_allowed = map { $_ => 1 } @allowed; 

foreach my $arg ( grep { not $is_allowed{$_} } @ARGV ) { 
   print "$arg is not valid\n";
}
```

You can set a flag in that foreach loop if you like, if you want to proceed. Or just use `grep` in a scalar context:

```
if ((grep { not $is_allowed{$_} } @ARGV) > 0 ) { 
   die "invalid args found, exiting\n"
}
```

Comment: Maybe `any` would be cleaner than `(grep ... ) > 0` ? And you left a `@pretend_ARGV` in the first version, I'm not sure if it's a left over of a test or if it's on purpose.

Comment: Possibly would be, yes. And yes, I used `@pretend_ARGV` for testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the valid arguments into a hash `%valid` (instead of an array `@arr`). Then you can do:

```
for (@ARGV) {
    push @not, $_ if !exists $valid{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[TIMTOWDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr=qw(cat rat mat sat);
my $ok = { map{ $_ => 0 } @arr};
my $wrong;
exists $ok->{$_} ? $ok->{$_}++ : $wrong->{$_}++ for @ARGV;

print "OK $_ : $ok->{$_}\n" for @arr;
print "NO $_ : $wrong->{$_}\n" for (sort keys %$wrong);
```

using

```
perl arg.pl bat cat ded rat mat foo bar foo cat
```

output

```
OK cat : 2
OK rat : 1
OK mat : 1
OK sat : 0
NO bar : 1
NO bat : 1
NO ded : 1
NO foo : 2
```

Comment: I'd stick a `1` in that map, so you can check for 'truth' as well as 'exists'.

Comment: @Sobrique Yikes! but as you seen, for the beginners like me, this is a bit more expressive. Ofc, youre right! :)